# CPPUNIT: How to create a instance of TestFixture using its name

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cppunit

I have two test classes called "**TT_Common**" and "**TT_Container**" which extends CPPUNIT_NS::TestFixture:

```
class TT_Common    : public CPPUNIT_NS::TestFixture ......
class TT_Container : public CPPUNIT_NS::TestFixture ......
```

And anoter class called TT_Runner which extends CPPUNIT_NS::TestRunner:

```
class TT_Runner : public CPPUNIT_NS::TestRunner
{
   .....
void run( CPPUNIT_NS::TestResult &controller, const std::string &testPath )
{

  CPPUNIT_NS::TestPath  path        = m_suite->resolveTestPath( testPath );
  CPPUNIT_NS::Test      *testToRun  = path.getChildTest();

  for ( size_t iIdx = 0; iIdx < testToRun->getChildTestCount(); iIdx++ )
  {
    CPPUNIT_NS::Test* psTest    = testToRun->getChildTestAt(iIdx);
    std::string       testName  = psTest->getName();
    // testName is TT_Common for iIdx = 0 and TT_Container for iIdx = 1
   }
 }
```

I already have the **name of the TestFixture** but how to create a **Instace** of it? I can't find a factory or registry which **takes the name and return a instance**.

Comment: Why do you want to instantiate a fixture manually? Fixtures are base classes for the tests. They may not do anything useful on their own.

Comment: I want to create multiple object of type TT_Common and TT_Container using its name to start the functions in context of these objects in multiple threads.

Comment: The tests will be automatically run in context of appropriate fixtures (each test in new instance). I still don't see why you should do it manually.

Comment: I want to have one instance for all test functions (some functions will depend on other functions). And for each Thread i need one of those instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not how fixtures work and not how tests work. A fixture is instantiated for each test separately, so the tests are isolated. And the tests are run *in unspecified order*, so they must not depend on each other.

Normally when you have functions that depend on each other, you just have a long test case that calls them all. If you want anything else, you really have to do it manually outside of cppunit.

Comment: you are right, usually test functions should not depend on other functions. I already have a self-written test environment which allows me to specify which function I want to call using XML (function order, call times, parameters, etc...). And I already have some test projects in CPPUnit. I try to enable these feature in my CPPUnit projects so that I have one test environment instead of two.